# What interesting stats can I obtain from the Stack Overflow data-dump?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, data-dump, statistics

What interesting statistics have you discovered from analysing the [Stack Overflow data-dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/)?

---

#### Related:

- [Blog post announcing the data-dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/)
- [Direct link to the .torrent (original XML files) (2009-06)](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/so-export-2009-06.7z.torrent)
- [Torrent for data in sqlite3 format by nobody_ (2009-06)](http://modos.org/so-export-sqlite-2009-06.torrent)
- [Torrent for data in MySQL format by Webber (2006-06)](http://torrents.thepiratebay.org/4959815/Stackoverflow%5Fdata%5Fin%5FMySQL.4959815.TPB.torrent)
- [Comment by Greg Hewgill describing the VoteTypeId values](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/#comment-24147)
- [Video on using Microsoft’s Free Data Mining Tools on the data-dump](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-tutorial/data-mining-the-stackoverflow-database/) ([alternative link on authors site](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/06/data-mining-the-stackoverflow-database/))
- A [tool that can load up the SO data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999185/is-there-a-script-or-program-that-will-efficiently-and-quickly-load-up-the-so-dum) into SQL Server really quickly.
- Dataset [loaded in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/stackoverflow).

Comment: thanks to your question, I came to know about the existence of the dump.

Comment: Not programming related and in the very least, this should be community wiki.

Comment: This should *definitely* be CW. I'm not going to vote to close though.

Comment: I'm not sure why this should be CommunityWiki'd? I want to encourage people to do contribute - rep is a good way of doing this, and CW question == CW answers (I don't personally care since I've now got more than enough :P).. This isn't a "Jon Skeet facts" or FAQ question - reasonable answers require a lot of effort (and *programming*!).. This answer on the CW sofaq pretty much sums up my view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128434/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow/426160#426160

Comment: @dbr: it's SO-related, not programming-related as such. Indeed, this has long been one of the categories where CW has proved most useful, by encouraging editing over posting, aggregating useful information over verbose navel-gazing. And FWIW, i find it hard to understand how you feel "penalized" by anyone here...

Comment: I disagree, but it's community wiki'd

Comment: 'i find it hard to understand how you feel "penalized" by anyone here...' - I do not, rather I want to "reward" others posting answers (by ~giving them rep)

Comment: What are you guys using to read/analyze these files? Are there any programs/libraries out there that won't choke on an 800MB XML file? I've been working on a program to parse the data and insert it into a SQLite database, but I'm wondering if there are any more direct approaches I could take instead.

Comment: @nobody_: any decent stream parser (SAX-based, etc) should be able to handle 800MB of XML easily. Just avoid DOM-based parsers!

Comment: @dbr: CW posts still get badges, which is a reward.

Comment: @nobody_ Xalan should do it.

Comment: Now that accept rate percentages are displayed I'm assuming that the rates for the most engaged users are going up as they accept answers on old questions. I'd like to see what questions haven't been given an accepted answer in that initial surge. e.g. a list of questions with no accepted answer from users with 95-99% accept rate.

Answer (score 32):

I used Wordle to visualise common substrings in titles (the bigger the more common and/or longer recurring phrases). I add some more fuzziness to my algorithm because there's awfully many synonyms in there.

[image]

Comment: That's one of the prettier visualisations of SO data I've seen so far! I agree it'd be nice to have phrases like "What is the best way" and "What's the best way" combined

Comment: Very cool! Can you post a high-res version of this?

Comment: +1 who knew "what is the best way" to ask a question? LOL

Comment: I find it ironic that now StackOverflow is [essentially](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169933/is-asking-for-programming-tool-recommendations-on-topic-on-stack-overflow) [banning](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222790/request-to-reopen-so-question-on-javascript-error-detection#comment725161_222790) ["what is the best"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211269/why-stackoverflow-doesnt-allow-comparison-questions-or-recommendations-for-tool) questions, despite them being the most sought after ones.

Comment: Nice. This cloud clearly shows that the main question people are interested in is "What is the best way/option to/of ...?" while unfortunately this is exactly what became disallowed to ask. I clearly remember how even my such question was deleted no matter how much people needed it. And I had no notification about the deletion. The Stack Exchange is just deleting our content silently. Deleting things that interest us the most.

Answer (score 21):

These are based on the `so-export-2009-06` data-dump..

## Boring stuff..

- Uncompressed there is 1.3GB of XML data (206.1MB compressed using `.7z`)

## Total number of..

#### .. users: 88,558 [1]

#### .. reputation points: 16,199,960 (average of ~182 rep per user) [2]

#### .. badges awarded: 234,599 [5]

#### .. questions: 182,742 [3]

#### .. answers: 698,923 [3]

#### .. votes: 2,379,537 [4]

```
UpMod                 1915441
DownMod                178300
AcceptedByOriginator   109549
Deletion                22107
Undeletion               1660
Close                    1492
BountyStart              1449
BountyClose              1379
Offensive                 365
Reopen                    121
InformModerator           112
Spam                       98
```

## Top Ten..

#### ..badges

```
Teacher           31416
Student           29526
Supporter         25362
Scholar           24150
Editor            23450
Nice Answer       22978
Autobiographer    12751
Critic            11609
Commentator        9831
Popular Question   8721
```

Also, each of the following badges was awarded only once: [6]

> - asp.net-mvc
> - best-practices
> - cocoa
> - django
> - eclipse
> - f#
> - iphone
> - jquery
> - language-agnostic
> - performance

#### .. viewed questions [7]

> 1. What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered? - 297,365 views
>
>    - What's your favorite "programmer" cartoon? - 140,287 views
>    - Programmer Jokes -- what's your best one? - 107,065 views
>    - What real life bad habits has programming given you? - 100,058 views
>    - Great programming quotes - 54,046 views
>    - What is your favorite "programmer" t-shirt? - 52,027 views
>    - Hidden Features of C# - 49,927 views
>    - The Coolest Server Names - 48,448 views
>    - Jon Skeet Facts? - 35,868 views
>    - How Does Stackoverflow Work? (The Official FAQ) - 34,614 views

#### .. voted questions [8]

> 1. What's your favorite "programmer" cartoon? - 682 votes
>
>    - How Does Stackoverflow Work? (The Official FAQ) - 621 votes
>    - Hidden Features of C# - 585 votes
>    - Could we please be a bit nicer to the noobs? - 451 votes
>    - Programmer Jokes -- what's your best one? - 385 votes
>    - What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered? - 359 votes
>    - Using what I've learned from stackoverflow. (HTML Scraper) - 352 votes
>    - What is the single most influential book every programmer should read? - 340 votes
>    - What do you use to keep notes as a developer? - 299 votes
>    - What real life bad habits has programming given you? - 269 votes

#### .. voted answers [9]

> - [84629](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84629) - 976 votes
> - [84624](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84624) - 745 votes
> - [164556](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164556) - 661 votes
> - [184673](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184673) - 621 votes
> - [234170](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234170) - 566 votes
> - [84576](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84576) - 551 votes
> - [234138](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234138) - 550 votes
> - [186309](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186309) - 544 votes
> - [234419](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234419) - 539 votes
> - [164451](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164451) - 512 votes

#### .. most answered question [10]

> 1. ["What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?" [184618]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618) - 533 points
>
>    - ["What real life bad habits has programming given you?" [164432]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164432) - 524 points
>    - ["Great programming quotes" [58640]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640) - 490 points
>    - ["The Coolest Server Names" [262657]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262657) - 450 points
>    - ["What do you use to keep notes as a developer?" [78756]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78756) - 389 points
>    - ["What was your first home computer?" [102714]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102714) - 373 points
>    - ["Programmer Jokes -- what's your best one?" [234075]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075) - 362 points
>    - ["What is the single most effective thing you did to improve your programming skills?" [76364]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76364) - 332 points
>    - ["What's your most controversial programming opinion?" [406760]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760) - 302 points
>    - ["What's Your Motto As A Developer/Programmer?" [81677]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81677) - 302 points

#### .. most comments on posts [11]

> 1. ["Since SQL Server doesn't have packages, what do programmers do to get around it?" [770300]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770300) - 107 comments
>
>    - [164556](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164556) - 83 comments
>    - ["How should disputes be handled on Stack Overflow?" [586611]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586611) - 79 comments
>    - [184673](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184673) - 65 comments
>    - ["Should I be discouraged by StackOverflow?" [587512]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587512) - 64 comments
>    - [423833](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423833) - 58 comments
>    - [383257](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383257) - 56 comments
>    - [629405](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629405) - 53 comments
>    - [318765](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318765) - 50 comments
>    - [706756](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706756) - 49 comments

### Graph..

#### .. age vs reputation

#### .. age vs account age

#### .. rep vs number of questions

#### .. rep vs number of answers

#### .. question-to-answer ratio

### Queries

Some of the above data was gathered using SQL queries on [this database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951056/what-interesting-stats-can-i-obtain-from-the-stack-overflow-data-dump/959661#959661). For future reference, here are the queries used to generate the data:

```
 1: select count(id) from users;
 2: select sum(reputation), sum(reputation)/count(id) from users;
 3: select posttypeid,count(id) from posts group by posttypeid;
 4: select votetypeid, count(id) from votes group by votetypeid;
 5: select name, count(name) from badges group by name order by count(name) desc limit 10;
 6: select name from badges group by name having count(name) = 1;
 7: select title, viewcount from posts order by viewcount desc limit 10;
 8: select title, score from posts where posttypeid = 1 order by score desc limit 10;
 9: select id, score from posts where posttypeid = 2 order by score desc limit 10;
10: select id, title, answercount from posts order by answercount desc limit 10;
11: select id, title, commentcount from posts order by commentcount desc limit 10;
```

Comment: You state the average rep per user as 184; John D. Cook is 364. Thoughts?

Comment: One thing that I want to do is verify the information in the dump before analyzing it. For example, the dump says my age is 22, but it's actually 21 (SO has it correct). I've checked a few other ages and they're all one more than they should be in the dump.

Comment: @nobody_ there is a bug in the dump. All the ages are one year older.

Comment: @Zifre: Is it confirmed that all ages are 1 more than they should be? I thought it might be a careless subtraction of the years - i.e. 2009-1987 = 22, but my birthday doesn't come until September so I'm still 21. However, there's a simple test - can someone that already had their birthday this year check their age and see if it's accurate or still +1?

Comment: @nobody_: I checked and mine is right, but it's not really a reference, as my birthday was last week...

Comment: Thanks nobody_, both for filling in a bunch of the headings, and the sqlite DB, which makes things.. slightly easier than parsing XML files!

Comment: ..opps, queries 8-10 are currently based on the 2009-05 database, only just noticed the June data-dump! I'll update them when the download completes

Answer (score 14):

There are 72 questions on SO that have an Answer marked correct that is both lower in score than the highest scoring answer **AND** are scored lower than -1.

Here is the list of bad, marked correct, answers:

- [Compare SQL Server Reporting Services to Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168427)    -25 36
- [Built-in types, when (not) to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911536)    -15 18
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216359    -15 46
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387801    -14 20
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277991    -12 35
- [Getting the array key in a 'foreach' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60032) -8  4
- [How are CSS frameworks used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435620)    -8  2
- [Is it safe to install SVN on a production win2008 web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154) -6  6
- [Static Constants in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842590)    -6  12
- [What could be the shortest way of checking function parameter , which might have values 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821415)    -5  12
- [What is Windows PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514492)    -5  19
- [What should we do to prepare for 2038?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239) -5  6
- [Largest prime factor of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287) -4  11
- [Python timedelta in years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765797)    -4  9
- [Where can I find a good implementation of Adapter Patterns with good examples in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812260)    -4  3
- [How to assign a select result to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807712)    -3  6
- [pointer to objects within a class, C++ newbie question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653423)    -3  5
- [Populating dropdownlist with selectlist in ViewData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609063)    -3  0
- [good postgresql client for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105788)    -3  3
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821653    -3  9
- [how to stop the execution of current method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746548)    -3  3
- [SELECT element in the multiple selection display style without allowing multiple selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900019)    -3  1
- [Is there a nullable datepicker that I can bind to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865572)    -3  4
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736670    -3  19
- [Regular expression to match DNS hostname or IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179)    -3  6
- [Programmatically align a toolbar on top of the iPhone keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158574)    -3  15
- [Serializable Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182873)    -3  4
- [UInt32 to Int32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210383)    -3  3
- [How to compile legacy VB6 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229868)    -3  6
- [Problems executing compiled 3.5 code on a server which only has the 2.0 framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167569)    -3  7
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418612    -3  13
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445642    -3  16
- [PHP templates - with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163834)    -3  3
- [A cool algorithm to check a Sudoku field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289537)    -3  11
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693388    -2  4
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536818    -2  3
- [How to make a numericupdown control for asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261164)    -2  2
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420371    -2  3
- [Code to create CAPTCHA code in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430615)    -2  8
- [How to convert an unreadable string back to UTF-8 bytes in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441563)    -2  4
- [Ruby: More flexibility than Java/C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404676)    -2  5
- [Howto: PHP/Javascript communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549427)    -2  0
- [XPath search with ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238697)    -2  1
- [What is the easiest algorithm to find the day of week of day zero of a given year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478694)    -2  6
- [How do foreach loops work in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398982)    -2  32
- [C# Data structure Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419638)    -2  6
- [Is there a Java unit-test framework that auto-tests getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108692)    -2  10
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112920    -2  25
- [how to send signal from one program to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637870)    -2  5
- [Why use Singleton to manage db connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703767)    -2  2
- [How should I do integer division in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539797)    -2  11
- [How do I find out what type each object is in a ArrayList<Object>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106336)    -2  8
- [LinqToSql Producing Different Sql Queries on Different Machines for Identical Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269594)    -2  1
- [ASP.NET MVC: Binding a Complex Type to a Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554790)    -2  1
- [Restricted autocompletion on combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868632)    -2  2
- [ELMAH SQL Error Handler database not available- what happens to logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758092)    -2  -1
- [Python dictionary: are keys() and values() always the same order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835092)    -2  10
- [Make VisualStudio C# have files/folders outside of the project directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717613)    -2  2
- [correct non www users to full www domain name in ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893781)    -2  1
- [How to increment a java String through all the possibilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342052)    -2  18
- [What's the result of the SQL statement "SELECT DATEADD(s,1234567890, '19700101')"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546921)    -2  3
- [Receiving a Java Method without using getDeclaredMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642532)    -2  3
- [C# app runs with debugging, but not without](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738327)    -2  2
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188321    -2  2
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537577    -2  61
- [Relative date/time for classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699686)    -2  1
- [byte[] to string to byte array conversion did not work fine in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891636)    -2  6
- [asp.net Convert CSV string to string[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73385) -2  5
- [WCF WebHttp Mixed Authentication (Basic AND Anonymous)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209795)    -2  0
- [How do I remove a specific number of files using python (version 2.5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296490)    -2  4
- [How much speed-up from converting 3D maths to SSE or other SIMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115291)    -2  1
- [What is the best way to extract a version string from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65994) -2  5

SQL:

```
select Id, 
    (select max(a.Score) from Answers a where a.ParentId = q.Id ) as MaxScore , 
    (select a.Score from Answers a where a.Id = q.AcceptedAnswerId) as  SelectedScore
into #t
from Questions q
where AcceptedAnswerId is not null 

select '- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/' + cast(Id as varchar) 
, SelectedScore
, MaxScore
from #t where SelectedScore < MaxScore
and SelectedScore < -1
order by selectedscore asc
```

Comment: I wonder what's caused the formatting to break - I looked at the source and it seems fine.

Comment: @waffles: the first one in the list, stackoverflow.com/questions/168427, does not seem to have an answer with a score of -25. Is it deleted, only visible to users with more than 10000 reputation?

Comment: @Peter, this list is months old, it needs updating

Answer (score 13):

No matter what Jeff says, Fastest Gun in the West is still a massive problem:

If you are the first to post an answer you have an almost 50% chance of it getting accepted, if you post the 5th answer you only have a 2% chance of getting your answer accepted.

Full results are below:

```
0   50477   46.305
1   26680   24.475
2   14516   13.316
3   7609    6.980
4   4023    3.691
5   2136    1.959
6   1244    1.141
7   790 0.725
8   521 0.478
9   285 0.261
10  193 0.177
11  125 0.115
12  116 0.106
13  66  0.061
14  43  0.039
15  40  0.037
16  28  0.026
17  25  0.023
18  15  0.014
19  14  0.013
20  8   0.007
21  4   0.004
22  2   0.002
23  5   0.005
24  8   0.007
25  1   0.001
```

```
select q.Id , 
    (  select count(*) from Answers a1 
            where a1.CreationDate < (select a2.CreationDate from Answers a2 where a2.Id = q.AcceptedAnswerId)
                and a1.ParentId = q.Id
    ) as AcceptedAnswerRank 
into #t
from Questions q
where AcceptedAnswerId is not null


select AcceptedAnswerRank, count(*), cast(((count(*) + 0.0) / (select count(*) + 0.0 from #t)) * 100.0 as Numeric(6,3))   from #t
group by AcceptedAnswerRank
order by AcceptedAnswerRank asc
```

Comment: How much do the stats change if you filter out questions with only one answer? (from a comment on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/is-the-fastest-gun-in-the-west-solved/99#99 )

Comment: @waffles: very nice stats, it's almost a geometrical progression :D

Comment: @waffles: Not sure, but it seems the 6th answer has a 2% chance of getting accepted.

Answer (score 9):

A couple of Questions here on MSO:

- [What makes a SOpedian’s profile worth visiting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2785/what-makes-a-sopedians-profile-worth-visiting-data-dump-analysis)
- [Is Jon Skeet slowly switching his attention from .net to Java?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12073/is-jon-skeet-slowly-switching-his-attention-from-net-to-java)

Answers with data dump analysis to other folk's Questions on MSO:

- [Are people too miserly with up votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128/are-people-too-miserly-with-up-votes/150#150)
- [Best time to ask Questions on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/best-time-to-ask-questions/9786#9786)

I'm very big on visualizing the data and make lots of graphs.  Here is one of my favorites:

Comment: Stu, the links no longer work. Any copies left?

Comment: @Anton nope, sorry.  long gone...i've removed links

Answer (score 7):

Well I've been mucking around with the data.

And came up with (a probably meaningless) stat that calculates the odds that when you post an answer it becomes accepted. Unfortunately there seems to be no way to filter out community wiki stuff (Jeff let me know this will be in the next dump). So that is mixed in.

For me when I post an answer about 21% percent of the time it will get accepted. The person with the highest ratio, is not Jon Skeet :) The prize goes to rq, who 73% of the time posts the accepted answer to a question. (I excluded people with less than 1000 reputation.)

Top 16 are:

```
rq                  4596    33  45  0.733333333 http://quirkygba.blogspot.com
Daniel LeCheminant  62055   113 189 0.597883598 
NULL                17637   16  27  0.592592593 NULL
Jb Evain            36702   19  34  0.558823529 http://evain.net/blog/
Todd White          30833   16  29  0.551724138 http://code.logos.com
Rafael              80720   24  44  0.545454545 http://kukawski.pl
Eric Rosenberger    41624   30  56  0.535714286 
Paolo Bergantino    16417   350 679 0.515463918 http://www.rootspot.com
Alex Koshelev       19772   17  33  0.515151515 http://webnewage.org/
Ben Gottlieb        6694    108 212 0.509433962 http://www.standalone.com
JeniT               6739    11  22  0.5         http://www.jenitennison.com/
Bittercoder         4843    18  36  0.5         http://blog.bittercoder.com
John Siracusa       164     19  38  0.5         http://arstechnica.com/staff/fatbits/
Ayman               40005   76  152 0.5         http://aymanh.com
Gdeglin             83491   33  66  0.5         http://www.inigral.com
Miles               64474   34  68  0.5

select OwnerUserId, case 
    when exists (select 1 from Posts p2 where p.ParentId = p2.Id and p2.AcceptedAnswerId = p.Id) then 1
        else 0 
    end as ItsRight
into #t
from Posts p 
where PostTypeId = 2


select OwnerUserId, sum(ItsRight) as [Accepted Answers], count(*) as [Total Answers],  
  (cast (sum(ItsRight) as float) / cast(count(*) as float)) as Ratio 
into #UserRatios
from #t
group by  OwnerUserId
having sum(ItsRight) > 0 and count(*) > 20 
order by cast (sum(ItsRight) as float) / cast(count(*) as float) desc

select DisplayName, r.*, WebsiteUrl, Reputation from #UserRatios r
join Users on Id = OwnerUserId
where Reputation > 1000
order by Ratio desc
```

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a small program to [import the data in a PostgreSQL database](https://www.bortzmeyer.org/stackoverflow-to-postgresql.html). My first analysis was on the interval between an article and the votes:

- 54 % of the votes occur the same day as the post ("[fastest gun in West](https://web.archive.org/web/20090416235123/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/pages/general/suggestions/24695)" syndrome)
- but you still have 27 % of the votes which occur more than a week after the post

[image]

I also studied the interval between a question and an **accepted** answer.

- 84 % of the accepted answers were posted on the same day as the question (again, the "fastest gun in West" syndrome)
- but 4 % were posted more than one week after the question.
- the longest delay is more than nine months (for "[Best method for varchar date validation in Sybase (T-SQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019/best-method-for-varchar-date-validation-in-sybase-t-sql)")

Graphs and technical details can be found in [my original article](https://www.bortzmeyer.org/stack-overflow-short-tail.html) (in French).

Comment: Because unverified users can't vote in this site, these result come.

Answer (score 6):

Using the [Elo rating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) to track how skilled<sup>(*)</sup> users are, one can conclude that users with high reputation, are also typically very skilled.

[image]
<sub>(source: [stackrating.com](http://stackrating.com/rep-vs-rating.png))</sub>

<sup>(*)</sup> Skill is defined in terms of "being able to provide answer that yields many upvotes".

Original Question/Answer:

- [Has anyone tried to estimate Stack Overflow users skill by analyzing the data dumps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255830/has-anyone-tried-to-estimate-stack-overflow-users-skill-by-analyzing-the-data-du/255831#255831)

Comment: What's so special about 1500?

Comment: It could been any number really. 1500 was the number chosen by USCF when keeping track of rating for chess players. See the Wikipedia article, section [Mathematical Details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system#Mathematical_details).

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some things I found from analyzing data that Jeff gave me before making the data generally available.

[Question statistics](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/04/15/stackoverflow-question-statistics/)

[Reputation statistics](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/03/02/stackoverflow-reputation-statistics/)

[Voting patters](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/04/12/civic-duty-on-stackoverflow/)

Comment: You state the average rep per user as 364; dbr's below is 184.  Thoughts?

Comment: John's analysis happened months ago; there have presumably been more users joining since.

Comment: Also, I imagine the data-dump will include more users than John's - the paragraph after only describes 61,213 users, the data-dump seems to contain 86,110

Comment: You should probably make this CW now that the question is.

Answer (score 0):

I added it all up in my head, and found that Jon Skeet's reputation velocity is a significant fraction of the speed of light.

Which is good, because photons could use the competition!