# What is spwho2.com and who manages it?

Tags: discussion, data-dump, site-usage

I accidentally visited this site today.

[http://spwho2.com](http://spwho2.com/)/

It contains most of the statistics of the users of Stackoverflow.

[My Profile](http://spwho2.com/Sites/StackOverflow/User/a7/76465/)

Is this a site managed by Stackoverflow? And what is the intention of it?

Answer (score 6):

It's all in the [about page](http://spwho2.com/news/about/):

> **What are these numbers and where are
> they from?**
>
> [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is a question & answer
> site for coders.  They [exported their
> database](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/) to let the community monkey
> around under the hood.
>
> We brought the numbers into SQL
> Server, and you can too – [I explain
> how to import the StackOverflow
> database at SQLServerPedia](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Data_Mining_the_StackOverflow_Database).
>
> **Who’s in
> charge here?**
>
> That would be me, [Brent Ozar](http://www.brentozar.com/) ([Twitter](http://twitter.com/brento)
> – [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26837/brent-ozar) – [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/users/431/brent-ozar)).  I’m a
> SQL Server expert for [Quest Software](http://www.quest.com/sql-server/).
> I help the StackOverflow guys out when
> they have SQL questions.  (I’m not
> saying I know the answers, ha ha ho
> ho, I just know people.)
>
> **Why is it
> named SP_Who2?**
>
> That’s a Microsoft SQL Server command
> that database administrators run when
> they wanna know who’s doing stuff
> inside the server.
>
> **Where can I go to
> talk about StackOverflow data?**
>
> Check out this [StackOverflow meta
> forum](http://sof.modos.org/forum/).

Comment: Yes.. But I am not clear about the intension.. Why we need such a site? Any practical uses?

Comment: It allows those of us that can't get to the datadump to access the data and get some useful statistics out of it. It is for the fun of it, and promotes and enhances SO.

Comment: It's just another way to look at the numbers... thinks programmers like to do isn't it ;-) It can also reveal things you didn't know before.

Answer (score 4):

[Brent Ozar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/26837/brent-ozar)  owns SPWho2 and he explains the details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7682/what-interesting-stats-can-i-obtain-from-the-stack-overflow-data-dump/7686#7686). It is based on the StackOverflow Data Dump and detailed as fretje mentioned on the About page.

As for the question why it is there I quote from Brent:

```
I've also built spwho2.com, a front end for some of the 
slicing and dicing I'm doing. I've got reports like:

 - Top 100 Tags Last Month
 - What question tags have the highest closed percentages?
 - What question tags get the most views?
 - What question tags get favorited the most often?
 - What question tags get the most answers?
 - What question tags are used by people with the highest reputations?

I'm working on reports about users, answers, badges and comments next.
```