# More stats on your user profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, personal-statistics

I'd like to see on my profile the percentage of answers that have been picked as correct answer, average votes on my answers etc.

Comment: I don't know how http://stackapps.com/ handles suggestions, but this may be better over there.

Comment: The first suggestion is a duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2238/would-it-be-useful-so-show-peoples-hit-rate-i-e-percentage-of-answers-accep

Comment: and I bet there's a Greasemonkey script for the second.

Comment: I'm actually developing an app off the API that does just what you're looking for and more. I'll have something to show by this weekend.

Comment: There was such a site at some time (http://spwho2.com/Sites/StackOverflow/). Unfortunately, it didn't get much traction and the maintainer (Brent Ozar) stopped maintaining it. Very sad, it was pretty awesome. Check google cache to get an idea). See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17231/what-is-spwho2-com-and-who-manages-it

Comment: There have been lots of requests for more stats such as this (for curiosity's sake, or to determine one's progress towards a particular badge), but there has always been resistance towards providing it. I'm eager to try out George's app.

Comment: @Ether Teaser: Think BF2S.com for Stack Overflow. :-)

Comment: Like to see that George :D

Comment: @BloodPhilia I'm having a lot of fun writing the app because I have all sorts of stats that I've been interested in. I can't wait until I have something that's 'showable'.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently writing an app for that using the Stack Overflow API.

I hadn't wanted to say anything before it was done, but I figure I may as well let the cat out of the bag.

Think of it like [BF2s.com](http://bf2s.com/player/45691375/) for Stack Overflow.

I plan on having an alpha version done this weekend (Work keeps getting in the way).  The domain has been purchased and the work continues.

Comment: Tell me if you need any help, I'm an MySQL/PHP developer myself. I can do some fair designing too.

Comment: hey, check out my profile there! http://bf2s.com/player/43557126/ though I only play BF2:BC now, which is awesome, although I haven't had ANY time for that recently

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: I haven't had a chance to play Bad Company either; I'm still enjoying Borderlands. Not to mention my PC is past its prime to play that at a good resolution.

Comment: How's it going with your app ;)

Comment: @BloodPhilia I finished the writing the repository and the underpinnings of the asynchronous polling process (for the update Queue) last weekend, and I've already sketched out the UI, so it's a matter of implementing the UI and polishing the experience. I anticipate it'll be this weekend before an alpha version is out, and then we'll go from there.

Comment: Need a name/logo? =D

Comment: @BloodPhilia I could use one, yea.

Comment: @BloodPhilia It's already registered at `http://stack-stats.com` (backwards joke to the hyphen site) but if you've got a better one I'm all ears.

Comment: @George - How about something like this: fruityjuice.nl/files/Stack-Stats-logo-text.png

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - What's up with the site :D? I can't wait!

Comment: @Bloodphilia Send me an email; via my contact link.  I re-wrote it because I found an easier way to do it, so it delayed launching. Now that it's re-written, I can continue. At this point I need to construct the view for the stats.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Sent you an email through the contact link on your blog! Hope I used the right one ;)

Comment: @bloodphilia if you didn't, that's my fault, not yours. :-)