# Statistics on number of questions asked daily/weekly

Tags: feature-request, statistics

It would be interesting to know how many questions are asked every day, understand how this number behaves over time and versus the number of visitors/users.

For example: is the "rate" of questions linear in the number of visitors? Polynomial? Maybe it has stronger relation to the number of subscribed users and not to visitors. You know, some stats fun.

I think that exposing several simple numbers will allow the community to calculate these graphs and stats, and give back to the StackOverflow family of sites by pointing out interesting statistical insights.

Comment: wouldn't this be derivable based on the Creative Commons data dumps?

Comment: Working with the data dump is overkill for the simple things I'm thinking about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StackOverflow data is publicly available.  This gives you the ability to roll your own stats. [Here is a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7682/what-interesting-stats-can-i-obtain-from-the-stack-overflow-data-dump) that gives you a whole bunch of info.