# How many questions are posted per day on Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, statistics

Like anyone, I'm interested in numbers (statistics). I would like to know the number of questions posted in Stack Overflow per day. If possible, how the numbers are growing/changing?

If we have this trend, we can even see the developer migrations between different languages/frameworks.

This can be applied to other Stack Exchange sites as well.

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic answers your first question.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65/stack-overflow-stats-graphs http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45169/how-many-so-users-use-the-site-per-day http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19316/statistics-on-number-of-questions-asked-daily-weekly

Comment: The #traffic link no longer seems to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[5,378 questions per day on average over the last two weeks](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic).

If you are interested in monitoring trends, you can use the [API's /info](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/info#filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true), monitor `questions_per_minute` and `answers_per_minute`, and build some awesome graphs ;) Right now it reports:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "total_questions": 3642574,
      "total_unanswered": 735504,
      "total_accepted": 2263501,
      "total_answers": 7158925,
      "questions_per_minute": 1.69,
      "answers_per_minute": 3.31,
      "total_comments": 15457244,
      "total_votes": 22628856,
      "total_badges": 3900808,
      "badges_per_minute": 1.81,
      "total_users": 1370392,
      "new_active_users": 42,
      "api_revision": "2012.9.6.3805"
    }
  ],
  "quota_remaining": 10000,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "backoff": 10,
  "has_more": false
}
```