# Worst answer on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, answers, down-votes

Today I found that the "worst" question (most downvoted) on Stack Overflow is *[Learning to write a compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156363/create-a-compiler-for-windows)*.

Is there a good way to find the "worst" answer?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11017/what-are-the-most-upvoted-downvoted-questions-and-answers-on-the-sites

Comment: @Jon Too bad half of those URLs do not work anymore...

Comment: Note that, as the answer to the linked question states, the most-downvoted answer is not the same as the answer with the lowest score. Kip's "256 is a nice round number" answer was downvoted quite a lot by people trying to keep it at a nice round number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to search for answers (in this way) right now.

You'll have to [download the latest data-dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/), or use a data-dump sandbox like [StackQL](http://jcoehoorn.dyndns.org/stackql/) to analyze the underlying data. [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7682/what-interesting-stats-can-i-obtain-from-the-stack-overflow-data-dump/7684#7684) looks like it has roughly what you need as far as a query goes, but the results in the answer are out of date.

Comment: Thanks I never knew about the dump.  Lots of interesting stats can be found using it.

Comment: @Lumpy: Yep. One thing to note is that all of the sensitive data in the data dump is anonymized (i.e., you can't see who has voted on what).

Answer (score 5):

In the time since [Jon Seigel's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48420/worst-answer-on-stack-overflow/48424#48424) was written, the `is:answer` search operator has been introduced.

So, you can search `is:answer`, sort by votes, and go to the last page of results.  [Here is the search URL](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer).

Currently, this is the *most downvoted* answer on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64242/rhino-mocks-typemock-moq-or-nmock-which-one-do-you-use-and-why/64278#64278

Though I wouldn't say it follows that the linked answer is the "worst" answer.