# Why Stackoverflow doesn't allow comparison questions or recommendations for tool

Tags: feature-request, support, stack-overflow, on-hold

Stackoverflow has very good Contributors,Developers and Tech Experts as a members
Why It doesn't allow me to ask a question to recommend or compare the tools,technology from the Experts available in the stack overflow.

In my case MonkeyTalk and Calabash both are a new technology in mobile automation testing.
Since I am a newbie to testing how can I get suggestions from Experts apart from stackoverflow(I asked this question after spending so many hours in google but didn't get anything)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537271/calabash-vs-monkeytalk-which-one-is-best-why
Stackoverflow put me on hold for this question

How can I get to know this answers from stack group.

Comment: [gorilla-vs-shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)

Comment: MonkeyTalk is the best because the name is more fun to say.

Comment: For those who can see deleted answers on SO, the answers to this tool recommendation question are great examples of what usually happens to these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610708/live-chat-integration-for-adaptive-websites . (The real sad thing there is that all the spam on that question was approved by reviewers.)

Comment: There is a [Software Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60887/software-recommendations) proposal in Area 51. You can support it if you would like such a site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stack Overflow is not a discussion board - it is a place to get definitive answers to specific questions.

Since "best" is subjective, it's difficult to provide a definitive answer to "what is the best ..." due to "best" being defined by the specific activity, the specific user, the intended use, and a whole variety of other factors.

Because of this, entire categories of questions are deemed off topic as they solicit opinions, rather than definitive answers.

Comment: but we can get to know what are all the pros and cons of both technology right.So that I can choose whatever I wish

Comment: Asking "which is best" isn't the way to get a list of pros and cons, and list questions is another type of question that is generally frowned upon

Comment: @MohammedYaseen what is a pro in ine use case may very well be con in another, so the only way to get solid answer is to describe your use case and ask how to achieve your goal. then hopefully you would get answers using both technologies. And if not, it means the other one is less suitable in the eyes of people able to answer ;) Just leave it open, maybe there is 3rd way you have no idea about, way better for you? So try to avoid listing tools unless you already chosen one and want to ask how to use it.

Comment: @Molot Thanks Now I've Changed my question in stack overflow ;)

Comment: @MohammedYaseen your edited question is still not good enough to reopen.  Instead of asking for a tool, you are soliciting opinions, which are off-topic as well.  The Q&A structure of Stack Overflow does not lend itself well to discussions and opinions.  You need to ask a specific question and get a specific answer.  Just throwing it out "Which is best and why" is not specific.

Answer (score 5):

These type of questions can lead to opinionated answers, and with that can, and often does, lead to arguments - neither of which are particularly useful.  Verified and proven facts are far more useful for all readers of the question.