# Has anyone tried to estimate Stack Overflow users skill by analyzing the data dumps?

Tags: discussion, users, statistics

Has there been any attempt to objectively estimate Stack Overflow users skill? If so, was any correlation between skill and reputation found?

To make the question more precise, let's assume skill to be defined as *"ability to provide answers that end up on top"*.

<sub><sub>*Disclaimer: Self answered question. Just wanted to share my findings since I think it could be of interest to the community. I've tried hard not to formulate this Q/A as a plug for the stackapp. Let me know if I failed, and how to improve it. (I'm also genuinely interested in more answers than my own.)*</sub></sub>

Answer (score 38):

> Has there been any attempt to objectively estimate Stack Overflow users skill?

Yes, this has been done in a recently released StackApp called [StackRating](https://stackapps.com/questions/6298/stackrating-tracks-skill-of-stack-overflow-users). Each question was seen as a "game", the responders were seen as "players" and the outcome of each game was determined by the votes. The players skill was then estimated using the [Elo rating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system).

In a nutshell it worked as follows: If you answer a question and get 20 upvotes, and I answer the same question and get 2 upvotes, then you have "won" and I have "lost". This will result in a positive rating update for you, and a negative rating update for me. The magnitude of the updates will depend on our current ratings; If you were higher rated than me, the result was expected, and our updates would be small. If on the other hand I had a higher rating than you, the result was unexpected and our updates would be large.

The key property of this approach to rating is that the ratings converge (as opposed to reputation which just grows and grows).

[cnicutar's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714501/cnicutar) rating has a very characteristic graph which illustrates this:

[image: A very characteristic graph]

For the details of how the scoring was implemented and what *K* value was used, see [the about page](http://stackrating.com/about).

> If so, was any correlation between skill and reputation found?

Well, high rep users tend to be skilled in the sense that they are good at writing answers that end up on top (big surprise). Whether this corresponds to being a good programmer is up for debate, but [arguments can be made](http://stackrating.com/about#interpret) that this is indeed the case.

The opposite is not true though. A low rep user can be an unskilled user or a skilled user (shouldn't come as a surprise either).

Perhaps someone who is more experienced with statistics can come to a more interesting conclusion. Here's the reputation *vs* rating plot:

[image: Reputation vs rating plot]

[Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) is the blue dot at the top, and [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) is the dot furthest to the right.

The full list of users can be found at http://stackrating.com.

Comment: I love how that looks like a candle, fluttering in a mild breeze. That mild breeze, of course, being the constant stream of farting from new and incompetent users. :)

Comment: Haha, well, new users (users with fewer than 100 answers) barely affect rating. (See how the *K* value is defined.)

Comment: Interesting. How do you count (if at all) questions with only one answer? Did you investigate whether not counting accepts changes things?

Comment: Questions with only 1 answer are not considered, and no, an accept is just treated as one extra upvote.

Comment: It strikes me that someone who is the only person capable of answering some given question is likely _very_ skilled! But I see why you can't include them.

Comment: +1 on question and answer, but I don't like your results for me :-) I often add answers (that may be should be comments sometimes) that either add to an existing answer or only answer part of the question. These seem to often get large negative deltas. Of course, there's also the problem of working in the "niche" VB.NET.

Comment: And some of my better answers are [Necromancers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer?userid=256431) :-(

Comment: @MarkHurd, regarding your first comment: This is unfortunate, but there's obviously no way to tell the difference between an answer that adds useful and insightful additions to an otherwise complete and well written answer, and a stand-alone substandard answer. This is inherent to the voting system which both rating and reputation builds upon. As for your second comment, there's a huge back-story that hasn't actually been told yet... See my next comment.

Comment: The reason for not taking answers that were posted >90 days after the question into consideration when computing the rating is due to many things. One reason is that new technology may have emerged and newer questions have an unfair advantage (i.e. upvotes don't relate well to skill). The other reason is that it's not obvious what initial rating to use. If you post an answer today, to a question that was posted last year, then you should reasonably be competing with the rating you have today... However, your "todays rating" is not known when judging games that were posted a year ago...

Comment: ...since I can't solve all rating equations in one gigantic equation system. The games need to be *linearized* in time. And if one of your opponent on that question also posts a necromancer answer, then there is a cycle in order in which games must be judged. For this reason, the games are linearized in the order according to the post time of the question. This means that you're "changing history" by posting a necromancers answer. The 90 day cutoff limits the impact of this.

Comment: This is a very interesting analysis, and I accept the conclusion that many of my answers are highly voted up. But I'm not convinced that there is that much of a correlation between being able to convincingly say "a bowl of apples is not a bowl of fruit", and being able to actually program computers.

Comment: I also note that in any analysis of "skill" where I am at the top and supercat is fourth from the bottom, *something* must be uncorrelated with reality. Supercat clearly has a deep knowledge of programming language design and semantics, and consistently gives thought-provoking comments and answers.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I feel like I could respond with an essay, but I'll try to keep it short. My desire and initial goal was to measure programming skill. I might have been able to pull that off if I had based the analysis on results from standardized programming tests or programming competition results. The Stack Overflow data reflects something else though. In my experience a good sense of didactics for example typically beats deep knowledge when it comes to upvotes, so if you ask me I'd say rating probably reflects something closer to pedagogical skill rather than...

Comment: ...programming skill. (The bowl of fruit answer is an example of pedagogical brilliance if you ask me.) That being said I do think being knowledgable in an area is a prerequisit for being a good teacher in the area. In other words, if you're a good programming *teacher*, chances are you're a good *programmer*. As I see it the converse is not necessarily true; Being a good programmer does not imply that you're a good teacher...

Comment: ...Supercat does indeed seem to have a deep knowledge of programming (and [electrical engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/3123/supercat)!), most likely deeper than I will ever have, but maybe he's not as strong in didactics.

Comment: @aioobe: I think your conclusion -- that you have found a metric for pedagogy -- is pretty reasonable. Something just struck me though -- this may also be a metric for knowing how to "pick your battles". In chess tournaments you don't get much choice about who you play, but I do get choice about which questions I choose to answer and which I leave alone, and that is influenced by who has already left answers.

Comment: very interesting. A few flaws in your algorithm: 1) You include answers that were deleted... those answers' life was stopped, so of course those would result in a "loss", but not a real one 2) you don't account for late answers. I saw a number of cases where i introduced a late answer, was rewarded with bounty and or accepted answer, but older answers had more votes (more exposure)

Comment: @DaveAlperovich 1) It's a simple counter measure against gaming the system. If you could delete all your answers with negative delta your rating would grow and grow and wouldn't reflect your skill at all. Also, if you decided to delete an answer it's not unreasonable to assume that you performed poorly and that the negative delta is deserved. 2) See my comment further up starting with *"The reason for not taking answers that were posted >90 days..."*

Comment: @aioobe, problem is you're inventing a new game and rules others are unaware of. If I were playing by your rules, I may double down and put more work toward my answer. I actually have deleted answers almost identical to later accepted answers. I often disengage when I find OP to ne difficult

Comment: Why is this a problem? Yes. If you put more effort into writing good answers, your answers will be of higher quality and your rating will be better. That's how it's supposed to work! So if you write an answer which is almost identical to another answer that later gets accepted then you were arguably slightly less skilled than the other poster. A negative delta update is therefore in place, regardless if whether or not you subsequently "regretted" posting it and deleted the answer. Sorry.

Comment: @aioobe, you're grading people on a different set of rules than the ones they play under. In SO, if I delete an answer, it doesn't exist any longer. That's how ALL users see it. You are grading them assuming opposite behavior. Obviously this is opinion based, but I see it as a big inaccuracy -- the way you assume people behave and the way they do behave. As I said, you've invented new rules, rules that you alone know.

Comment: Actually, it's the same rules: You post an answer, others judge the quality of it by voting. The difference lies in what is being measured. Suppose you post an answer, get downvoted, then delete it. Your net contribution to the community (which is roughly what reputation measures) is 0, so your rep delta is 0. If someone else posted an answer (to the same question) which gets upvoted, it has however been shown that you perform worse than the other poster. This is a fact that holds regardless if you are aware of the StackRating mechanics or not, thus a negative rating delta is correct/fair.

Comment: @aioobe, In a case where an answer was deleted due to down votes, I agree. But what about the times when OP attitude wasn't good so user didn't feel they could help. One of my answers where I "lost", I had accepted answer and the other player had 1 more vote than I did -- Mine. I was the "winning" vote for the opponent. That's "sportsmanship". My intention was the exact opposite of what you assumed. Answerer's on SO don't see themselves in a competitive win-or-lose game of getting most votes. Every vote up is a victory by current game. You assume intent which is often wrong.

Comment: @DaveAlperovich, to me this comes across as that you are bitter over outcomes over specific posts rather than systematic flaw in the algorithm. Keep in mind that the rating is stable. Rating lost in an undeserved way *will* be regained in subsequent posts. Even if you loose due to "sportsmanship" in the *majority* of all your posts, your rating will still reflect your ability. This is inherent property of the Elo formula.

Comment: @aioobe, very interesting point. The morw we exchange  views, the more i feel your goal is self promotion at the expense of quality results. Which is your right as you created the application. You seem intent on rewarding your way and get fighty at any suggestion of change. Had I understood that at the outset, I never would have upset you with any of my concerns.